# Launch external spark program inside a scala spark program

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a huge iterative program which tends to diverge in time. Iterations take more and more time as time goes by. So I think decomposing the problem in sub-programs that will run kind of independently will allow spark and the JVM to better allocate memory.

**First question** is : do you think there is effectively some performance to gain with the proposed method ?

**Second question** is : how ?

I tried to run a spark-submit command inside a scala program like this:

```
import sys.process._
"cmd /C spark-submit --master local --class org.HelloWorld \\path\\helloworld.jar".!!
```

Which work fine on Windows but obviously not in Linux. I tried to adapt it for Unix system like this but it is not working :

```
Seq("bash", "-c", "spark-submit --master local --class org.HelloWorld \\path\\helloworld.jar")!!
```

It throws :

```
bash: spark-submit : command not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 127
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:132)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
```

**Although I can run it successfully by hand on bash terminal**.

I also found that it exists a `org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher`. But whenever I try to create a an object like this : `val spark = new SparkLauncher()` I got a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher`

Do you have any solutions or suggestions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run your bash by hand from the name of the spark user, you probably will be able to run the bash interpreter from the code. So you can create bash file with your spark app, save it and run bash using `sys.process` API. Hovewer you can also try to use full path to spark-submit executable as probably `sys.process` don't know where your executable actually is.

Comment: Using full path to spark-submit executable solved my problem. Thanks.